# PyCharm, Python3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am a beginner to Python and have begun by using the PyCharm IDE. Whenever I run a program, I get a long list of errors in the console that goes like:

> Exception in thread pydevd.CheckAliveThread: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/threading.py",
>   line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd_comm.py", line 252, in run
>       self.OnRun()   File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 188, in OnRun
>       self.stop()   File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd_comm.py", line 262, in stop
>       _Thread_stop(self)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/threading.py",
>   line 990, in _stop
>       assert not lock.locked() AssertionError

...

> AssertionError Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 997, in
>   trace_dispatch
>       if not t.isAlive():   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/threading.py",
>   line 1117, in is_alive
>       self._wait_for_tstate_lock(False)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/threading.py",
>   line 1073, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
>       assert self._is_stopped AssertionError

Process finished with exit code 0

The program runs, but having that every time is really annoying. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Why are you using Python 3.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm does not yet support Python 3.4, however support is coming in version 3.1 which is poised to arrive early 2014. Here is the link the the [blog-post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2013/11/meet-the-pycharm-3-1-roadmap/).

I would suggest that you use 3.3 for now to do your work.

Answer (score 1):

Version 3.1, now available, [supports Python 3.4](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/index.html) in both the Professional and "Community" editions.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12317) posted on Jetbrain's tracker.

I'd suggest up voting the bug so it receives attention.
The bug seems to describe the problem you are seeing. 
I'm seeing the same issue, but I can switch to Python 3.3 for now.

Answer (score -1):

Try install python 3.3 ( maybe it's help you). Do you have win64 or win32?

Comment: Since the paths begin with `/Library`, chances are it's Mac OS X.